# What does this double integral even represent?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm preparing for a calculus resit and I'm really confused by this double integral. I somewhat understand where the $\int_{3y}^{12-3y}$ comes from (just expressing $y=\frac{1}{3}x$ and $y=-\frac{1}{3}(x-6)+2$ in terms of x). I also get how to solve the integral (my answer was also 8), but now what this answer actually represents.

$$\int_0^2 \int_{3y}^{12-3y} (y)\ dx\ dy = 8$$

If you plot these two functions, the area enclosed by them and the x-axis is obviously 12 (just the area of two right-angled triangles, and I even checked it with integrals to make sure I wasn't going mad). I believe the double integral represents some sort of volume, but I don't understand what volume, because nowhere in this question a z-axis is mentioned.

I feel like I'm either missing something very fundamental, or this is just a really badly worded/confusing question. Either way, any help would be very much appreciated! :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The defintion of $y$ is not obvious. Both functions are named $y$.

Comment: About the z axis - you integrate the function $z(x,y)=y$ over the 2d region of integration.

Comment: One interpretiation: If you have some region $A$ then $\frac{\iint y dA}{\iint dA}$ is the $y$ coordinate of the center of mass of that region and you can likewise do the same for $x$ to get the "center" point of the region (both integrals is over $A$ and the denominator is just the area of the region).

Comment: ... assuming unifrorm density.

Comment: @Winther I personally didn't really understand what you meant but it sounded interesting. Please explain it in an answer if you have the time!

Comment: @Koncopd I think this is probably the intended answer of this question. I guess the $z(x,y) = y$ is just sort of "implied" by the definition of that double integral $\int \int_D y\ dA$? So it would basically be like taking the defined area, and turning it 90° in the z-axis, and then taking the volume of the resulting shape?

Comment: Treating the integrand as $z(x,y)=y$ gives a geometrical interpretation where you are trying to find the volume of a pyramid whose base is the triangle $D$. Two of its sides are perpendicular to the $xy$-plane, and the third is given by $z(x,y)=y$. Its apex is over the point $(6,2)$, so the height is $2$. From this you can verify that the volume is $12\times 2/3=8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we consider a double integral lets think about what a single integral represents.
The usual interpretation of a single integral is the area under a curve.
So
$$ \int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $$
represents the area between the $x$ axis (which is just $y=0$), the lines $x=a$, $x=b$ and $y=f(x)$.
This often a valid and useful interpretation but it isn't the only interpretation.
Another interpretation may arise with a more specific function. Say we have some string with length $L$ and we know that its mass per unit length at some point $x$ along the string is given by $\rho(x)$. Then the total mass of the string can be expressed as [[1](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/06%3A_Applications_of_Integration/6.5%3A_Physical_Applications_of_Integration)]
$$m = \int_0^L \rho(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $$
To see why this is the case we think about what an integral is, really its just a sum of lots of infinitesimal bits (excuse the hand waving, I'm a physicist).
So a discrete version of the integral above may be
$$ m \approx \sum_i \rho(x_i) \Delta x $$
where we approximate the integral as a sum and we split the string into finite lengths $\Delta x$ and we consider the density at the point $x_i$ within each length to be a good approximation of the density of the whole length.

Personally I think that this interpretation of the integral is better suited for generalisation to higher dimensions.
We can similarly consider a function like $\sigma(x, y)$ which represents the density at a point $(x, y)$ on a plane. Then the integral
$$ \iint_S \sigma(x, y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y $$
is just the mass of the surface, $S$, over which we are integrating.

There is still a valid interpretation of a double integral as a volume however.
Imagine that the function $f$ represents the height above the $x,y$-plane.
Then the integral [[2](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DoubleIntegrals.aspx), [3](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/double-integrals-a/a/double-integrals)]
$$ \iint_S f(x, y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y $$
represents the area between the $x,y$-plane and the function $f$ only above the volume in the $x,y$-plane that we call $S$.
This interpretation can still hold even if we haven't got an explicitly constructed $z$-axis to think of the height as being along since this interpretation is just to aid in our thought process.

Notice how similar this is to the one-dimensional case with all dimensions shifted up by one. Single integrals become double integrals, intervals such as $[a, b]$ become regions of the plane, $S$, and areas, given by single integrals, become volumes, given by double integrals.
The problem comes when we want to evaluate a triple integral and then with the "area under a curve" interpretation we have to consider the 4-dimensional hyper-volume under a volume and I don't know about you but that is *not* something I can picture.

So to answer your specific question, what does the given integral represent, the answer is: it depends.
This is sort of a rubbish answer but it is true.
If the function we are integrating, in this case simply $y$ is naturally thought of as a height then a volume is a valid interpretation (and probably the best interpretation in this case). If it can be thought of as a density then mass is probably a better interpretation. However both of these are just ways of thinking about the integral and really they are the same, we can view mass as simply a coordinate in some "mass-space" in a similar way to how we might consider [momentum space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space) or any other more abstract space.

Comment: Damn, that is one elaborate answer! Thank you so much, really appreciate it!  :)